# How to run Intel DPDK application in a virtual machine?

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

Anyone managed to run Intel DPDK-based application in a virtual machine?

I have an application based on DPDK which I'm trying to bring up inside VirtualBox.

Intel mentions paravirtualized network interfaces in its documentation but I could not find any specific instructions related to virtual machine compatibility.

The application fails with the following error:

```
EAL: coremask set to 3
EAL: 0 hugepages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
PANIC in rte_eal_init():
Cannot get hugepage information
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drivers suitable for virtualization are:

- e1000
- igbvf
- ixgbevf
- virtio-net
- vmxnet3

In VirtualBox, you should first try with a basic e1000 device.

About your problem "no mounted hugetlbfs", you must do this:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/huge
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge
echo 64 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

You should refer to the [quick start guide](http://dpdk.org/doc/quick-start).

Comment: Thanks, I found we can get it running on KVM but on Windows VirtualBox we got kernel panic, so we will move to KVM