# Error in running DPDK L2FWD application on a container managed by Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dpdk

I am trying to run DPDK L2FWD application on a container managed by Kubernetes.

To achieve this I have done the below steps -

- I have created single node K8s setup where both master and client are running on host machine. As network plug-in, I have used Calico Network.
- To create customized DPDK docker image, I have used the below Dockerfile

> FROM ubuntu:16.04  RUN apt-get update
>   RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
>   RUN apt-get install -y python
>   RUN apt-get install -y kmod 
>   RUN apt-get install -y iproute2
>   RUN apt-get install -y net-tools 
>   ADD ./dpdk/ /home/sdn/dpdk/
>   WORKDIR /home/sdn/dpdk/

- To run DPDK application inside POD, below host's directories are mounted to POD with privileged access:

> /mnt/huge
>   /usr
>   /lib
>   /etc

Below is k8s deployment yaml used to create the POD

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dpdk-pod126
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dpdk126
    image: dpdk-test126
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "2Gi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: hostvol1
        mountPath: /mnt/huge
      - name: hostvol2
        mountPath: /usr
      - name: hostvol3
        mountPath: /lib
      - name: hostvol4
        mountPath: /etc
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
  volumes:
  - name: hostvol1
    hostPath:
      path: /mnt/huge
  - name: hostvol2
    hostPath:
      path: /usr
  - name: hostvol3
    hostPath:
      path: /home/sdn/kubernetes-test/libtest
  - name: hostvol4
    hostPath:
      path: /etc
```

- Below configurations are already done in host -

  1. Huge page mounting.
  2. Interface binding in user space.
- After successful creation of POD, when trying to run a DPDK L2FWD application inside POD, I am getting the below error -

> root@dpdk-pod126:/home/sdn/dpdk# ./examples/l2fwd/build/l2fwd -c 0x0f -- -p 0x03 -q 1
>   EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
>   EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
>   EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
>   EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
>   EAL: 1007 hugepages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
>   EAL: FATAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
>   EAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
>   EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
>   Cause: Invalid EAL arguments

Comment: Can someone help me out to solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: DPDK log `EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB` is not an error but an warning like information it has not found 1GB mount on the platform. This means for x86 there is 2MB pages in the system which is seen by the application. But `EAL: 1007 hugepages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size` means the application does not have access to huge pages. In your case access from host to docker|kubectl node is absent. So my suggestion is to check file or folder permission to ensure the node can access the mounted hugfe page from host.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-hugepages/scheduling-hugepages/), you might be missing
   `medium: HugePages` from your hugepage volume.

Also, hugepages can be a bit finnicky. Can you provide the output of:
`cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge`
and check if there's any files in `/mnt/huge`?

Also maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19090490/6268689) can be helpful. Can you somehow check if the hugepages are being mounted as `mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to verify, that you have enough hugepages in your system. Check it with `kubectl` command:

```
kubectl describe nodes
```

where you could see something like this:

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  129719908Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      8Gi
  memory:             65863024Ki
  pods:               110
```

If your `hugepages-2Mi` is empty, then your k8s don't see mounted hugepages

After mounting hugepages into your host, you can prepare your pod to work with hugepages. You don't need to mount hugepages folder as you shown. You can simply add emptyDir volume like this:

```
  volumes:
  - name: hugepage-2mi
    emptyDir:
      medium: HugePages-2Mi
```

`HugePages-2Mi` is a specific resource name that corresponds with hugepages of 2Mb size. If you want to use 1Gb size hugepages then there is another resource for it - `hugepages-1Gi`

After defining the volume, you can use it in volumeMounts like this:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /hugepages-2Mi
      name: hugepage-2mi
```

And there is one additional step. You have to define resource limitations for hugepages usage:

```
    resources:
      limits:
        hugepages-2Mi: 128Mi
        memory: 128Mi
      requests:
        memory: 128Mi
```

After all this steps, you can run your container with hugepages inside container

As @AdamTL mentioned, you can find additional info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-hugepages/scheduling-hugepages/)